# How to make Interactions with different `AngularJS 1.58` components?

Tags: angularjs, components

When I click the `Not heart` `div`, all `Not heart` div must hide and all `Hearted` div will show. When I click the `Hearted` div, all `Hearted` div must hide and all `Not heart` div will show. The same interaction to `collection` component.  When the `hearted` div is showing, the heartNumber have to add 1.   When the `Not heart` div is showing, the heartNumber have to delete 1.

```
My application architecture is like this:
```

[image]

`heart` folder is on:
https://jsfiddle.net/jiexishede/Ltsgnn86/1/

`collection` folder is on:
https://jsfiddle.net/jiexishede/hq6dju3c/1/

`show` folder is on:
https://jsfiddle.net/jiexishede/e9bxf1f9/1/

The code in `index.html`  is below :

```
   <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <heart is-heart="heartBoolean"></heart>
    <collection is-collection="collectionBoolean"></collection>
</div>

<div>
    <shownumber collection-number="10" heart-number="10"></shownumber>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <heart is-heart="heartBoolean"></heart>
    <collection is-collection="collectionBoolean"></collection>
</div>

</body>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="collection/collectionComponent.js"></script>
<script src="heart/heartComponent.js"></script>
<script src="show/showComponent.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
        $scope.heartBoolean = true;
        $scope.collectionBoolean = true;
    })
</script>
<script>
    collectionComponentFactoryFun('app','./collection');
    showComponentFactoryFun('app','./show');
    heartComponentFactoryFun('app','./heart');
</script>
```

**Now, I have changed the text in the demo. The demo uses the variable named collectionBoolean and the variable named heartBoolean.  If you change the boolean state in the `component`. I will vote your code, due to your code is not coupled.**

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is not too late.... According to what I see in your code I reckon that the main issue is with the way that you are setting up your main module and components.

I've just worked around a little bit I came up with this hope it will work.

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

angular
  .module( 'plunker' )
  .controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
      $scope.isHeart = true;
      $scope.isCollection = true;
  });

var HeartCtrl = function () {

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
          var isHeart = angular.copy( ctrl.isHeart );
          console.log( 'isHeart : ', isHeart );
      };

    ctrl.$onChanges = function ( changes ) {
        if ( changes.isHeart  && !changes.isHeart.isFirstChange() ) {
            ctrl.isHeart = angular.copy( changes.isHeart );
        }
    };

    ctrl.clickHeartFun = function (boolean_number) {
          ctrl.isHeart = boolean_number;
      };
};

angular
        .module( 'plunker' )
        .component( 'heart', {
            bindings: {
               isHeart : '<'
            },
            templateUrl  : 'heart.tpl.html',
            controller  : HeartCtrl
        });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RJwYJ2iAxEQOV5jBwyXj?p=preview